# "Find by attribute" plugin UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: qgis

This is the error message, when launching the plugin. I hope this is the right place, where to report this kind of message.

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/saabrs/.qgis//python/plugins/findbyattr/Findbyattr.py", line 66, in run
>       tempname = str(name).rstrip('01234567890')
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0161' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 23:06:40) 
>   [GCC 4.6.3]
>
> QGIS version:
>   1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, exported
>
> Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/saabrs/.qgis//python', '/home/saabrs/.qgis//python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '~/.qgis/python', '/home/saabrs/.qgis/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms', '/home/saabrs/.qgis/python/plugins/QuickMultiAttributeEdit/forms', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools', '/home/saabrs/Darbvirsma/mag/gis']

Comment: Posting a question on Stackexchange is not the same as reporting a bug. See here for instructions on reporting a bug with QGIS: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the search options located into Attributes Dialog Box.